# Подскажите как настроить кеширование apache + nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер

Никак не могу понять как включить кеширование в nginx + apache для браузера.

Перетыкал уже все варианты которые нашел в гугле, но кеширование почему-то не включается.

С nginx никогда не работал, с апачем чуть получше.

Сайт достался в наследство, работает на opencarte.

Заголовок ответа сервера

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 04:59:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dgaoi1d84popfej16f5b8go8e5; expires=Sun, 17-Jul-2016 04:59:33 GMT; path=/
Expires: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 04:59:33 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Set-Cookie: language=ru; expires=Sun, 17-Jul-2016 04:59:33 GMT; path=/; domain=mysite.ru
Set-Cookie: currency=RUB; expires=Sun, 17-Jul-2016 04:59:33 GMT; path=/; domain=mysite.ru
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 04:39:33 GMT
```

Конфиг nginx

```
#######################################################################
#
# This is the main Nginx configuration file.  
#
# More information about the configuration options is available on 
#   * the English wiki - http://wiki.nginx.org/Main
#   * the Russian documentation - http://sysoev.ru/nginx/
#
#######################################################################

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Module - directives that cover basic functionality
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Events Module 
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpEventsModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTTP Core Module
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule 
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #
    # The default server
    #

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    client_max_body_size 16m;
    log_format  isp '$bytes_sent $request_length';
    server {
        listen 10.12.10.141:80;
        server_name mysite.ru *.mysite.ru www.mysite.ru;
        rewrite ^(/manager/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
        error_page 404 = @fallback;
        location ~* ^/(webstat/|awstats|webmail/|myadmin/|manimg/) {
            proxy_pass http://10.12.10.141:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://mysite.ru:8080/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.12.10.141:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://mysite.ru:8080/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar)$ {

            access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.ru.access.log ;
            access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/mysite.ru isp;
            set $proot "/var/www/mysite.ru/data/www/mysite.ru";
                        expires    24h;

            if ( $host = "mysite.ru" ) {
                break;
            }
            if ( $host = "www.mysite.ru" ) {
                break;
            }
            if ( $host ~* ^(.*).mysite.ru$ ) {
                set $proot /var/www/mysite.ru/data/www/mysite.ru/$1;
                break;
            }
            root $proot;
        }
        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://10.12.10.141:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }


    }
}
```

.htacces апача

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files

Deny from 10.10.12.10

#<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif)$">
#    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, must-revalidate"
#</FilesMatch>



<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>



# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /


#Создание ссылок ЧПУ

###RewriteRule ^$1/$2/$3 /index.php?route=$1/$4&path=$2&product_id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.html$ index.php?route=information/sitemap [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^catalog\.html /index.php?route=product/category [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^news\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/news$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^works\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/works$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^articles\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/articles$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)\.html /index.php?route=information/reviews&rreview_id=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^reviews\.html(.*) /index.php?route=information/reviews$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^information/([^?]*) index.php?route=information/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([^?]*) index.php?route=product/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cache_([^?]*) cache.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^news/([^?]*) /index.php?route=information/news/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
##RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /eksklyuzivnaya-vinnaya-kollekciya/ http://mysite.ru/vino/eksklyuzivnaya-vinnaya-kollektsiya/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /Vieil_Armagnac_Sempe_1948_Sempyе_V_ei_Arman_jаk-v_podar_up/  http://mysite.ru/krepkie-napitki/armanyak/vieil-armagnac-sempe-1948-sempe-vej-armanyak-v-podarup/ [R=301,L]
#Redirect 301 /Dopff_au_Moulin_Dopf_o_Mulen/ http://mysite.ru/dopff-au-moulindopf-o-mulen/


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://mysite.ru/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^yandexmarket.xml$ index.php?route=feed/yandex_market [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

Comment: судя по содержимому заголовка `content-type`, скорее всего, этот ответ сформирован *php*-скриптами. с большой вероятностью, заголовки, влияющие на кэширование на клиентской стороне (`expires`, `cache-control`, `last-modified`), сформированы ими же.

Comment: т.е. кэшированные включено?

Comment: *т.е. кэширование включено?* — ответ на этот вопрос зависит от того, что именно вы подразумеваете и под словом «кэшированием» и под словом «включено». // просто к слову: я бы лично охарактиризовал содержимое перечисленных заголовков выражением «противоречивый бардак».

Answer (score 1):

Вы сталкиваетесь с этой проблемой скорее всего из-за использования сессий. Ознакомьтесь с этой замечательной статьёй о кешировании в nginx: https://habrahabr.ru/post/124684/ (а так же комментариями).

В кратце - если у вас начинается сессия в PHP, то добавятся заголовки, которые вы и указали - `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache`. Что бы этого избежать - начинайте сессию только тогда, когда это действительно необходимо (в статье описано как это сделать). Ну и проверьте код на отсылаемые заголовки, возможно где-то отправляется `Cache-Control: no-cache` от которого можно отказаться.